# Am I able to install Eclipse Oxygen on Ubuntu MATE 16.04 without using the installer?

Tags: eclipse, mate

I'm not very good at wording things but is there anyway I can install Eclipse Oxygen without using the installer. I am currently not able to run Linux executables and I'm looking for a way to get the program installed without using any executable installer.

Any help is helpful. Thanks.

Comment: According to your comments in my answer you're running some ubuntu on ARM computer, so my answer is not helping. I will remove it.

Comment: No worries, I'm switching over to Open SUSE as it's more fitting to me.